# Syntax error in nested IF statement

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, primes

I need a procedure that verifies if a number is prime. The syntax appears to be fine, but a get the following error:

> Query : CREATE PROCEDURE prime_number(IN n INT) BEGIN  SET @prime = "Prime number";  SET @n_prime = "Not prime number";  SET @divider = ...
>
> Error Code : 1064
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 28

Here's my code so far:

```
DELIMITER $
CREATE PROCEDURE prime_number(IN n INT)
BEGIN
    SET @prime = "Prime number";
    SET @n_prime = "Not prime number";
    SET @divider = 0;
    SET @i = 5;
    IF n % 2 = 0 THEN
        SELECT @n_prime;
        
    ELSEIF (n < 2) OR ((n % 3) = 0) THEN /* Was using ELSE IF, separatedly*/
        SELECT @n_prime;
        
    ELSE
        SET @root = SQRT(n);
        
        WHILE @i <= @root && @divider = 0 DO
            IF (n % @i) = 0 THEN
                SET @divider = 1;
            END IF;
            SET @i = @i + 1;
        END WHILE;
        
        IF @divider = 1 THEN SELECT @n_prime;
        ELSE SELECT @prime;
        END IF;
    
    END IF; /*Line 28*/
END $
DELIMITER ;
```

Any ideias why it's happening?

Comment: Are you going to tell us which line is 28, or are we all supposed to count?

Comment: Sorry, i'm going to include a indication at the line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is most likely `ELSE IF`. That creates another `IF` statement that requires another `END IF`. You want to use [`ELSEIF`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/if-statement.html) instead.

Comment: I see. You have a third mistake.

Comment: It worked! Thanks! SQL is not my primary language, and i'm still learning it.